# Match all control characters but line break \n

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way to write a regex that matches any [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) except the line break `"\n"`?

I can write a regex to catch any of the control characters like so:

```
/\p{Cc}/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/(?!\n)\p{Cc}/
```

Negative lookahead, shouldn't match line breaks

Comment: You could write `str.gsub(/./) { |c| c.match?(r) ? c : '' }, where `r` is your regex. Is that what you had in mind for extracting the non-newline control characters (or perhaps something else)?

Comment: If you are inside a script that needs double escape character: pattern = "(?![\\n])\\p{Cc}". The difference between "(?![\\n])\\p{C}" and "(?![\\n])\\p{Cc}" is that the first pattern will match and remove all control and whitespace characters except for newlines, while the second pattern will match and remove all non-whitespace control characters, leaving newlines and other whitespace characters in the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Q\cA\n\cD%\cH\n"       #=> "Q\u0001\n\u0004%\b\n"

str.gsub(/[^\p{Cc}]|\n/, '')  #=> "\u0001\u0004\b"
```

Note that

```
"\cH" #=> "\b"
```